# QLable текст разным фоном, цветом

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Всем привет. Как в `Qlable` можно вывести текст, в таком виде как он представлен на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом "аааааа", "ббббб" и "ссссс" получаем из переменных.
Я пробовал использовать `label->setSelection(i, j)`, а также псевдо-состояние `:selected` но ничего не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте HTML тэги:

```
label->setText("aaaaaa<FONT SIZE=5 COLOR=#FF0000>bbbbb</FONT>ccccc");
```